# Get SSL certificate info - UIWebview

Tags: ssl, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

How can i get the certificate info?

I'm using Uiwebview and need to get the certificate information for some reason ,
I can't find way to do this ..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

SSL certficates are provided over a domain (stored on the web servers). To get certificate information you can use online utlities like sslshopper and digicert. To get the key you can go to the certificate directory /etc/pki/tls/certs (in linux) or C:\Apache2\certs (in windows).